# Webpack module build failed unexpected token (rails react build)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I working on a react/rails build and working through using webpack and babel for the first time. I'm using two files and getting **the error**:

> ERROR in ./app/assets/frontend/main.jsx
>       Module build failed:
>       SyntaxError:  /Users/cls/GitHub/rails_react/app/assets/frontend/main.jsx: Unexpected token (6:6)

Line 6 is: `<Greet />`

**This is the main.jsx file**

```
import Greet from './greet';

class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Greet />
        );
    }
}
let documentReady = () => {
    React.render(
        <Main />,
        document.getElementById('react')
    );
};
$(documentReady);
```

**This is the greet.jsx file:**

```
export default class Greet extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h2>Hello There</h2>
    }
}
```

This is my webpack.config:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/assets/frontend/main.jsx",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/app/assets/javascripts",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

I don't have a babelrc file?

Comment: Can you post your webpack config and your babelrc files?

Comment: Also `$(documentReady)` is completely unnecessary

Comment: Also do you have `import React from 'react'` at the top of your files that use JSX? Usually you need that.

Comment: I added the `import React from 'react' ` and changed the  `$(documentReady)` but I still have the same error

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you know what version of babel-core you have? If it's 6 then you need to add a bunch of stuff. (plugins, .babelrc file)

Comment: @azium I'm running 6.4.5

Comment: I followed the course on Pluralsight, and having the same issue.

Comment: where is `webpack.config` located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So with all the feedback given I was able to figure it out.  Thank you to everyone who answered.

Here is what I needed to do:

`npm install babel-preset-es2015`

`npm install babel-preset-react`

And create a .babelrc file (**thank you to azium and Kreozot**)

```js
`{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "es2015"
  ]
}`
```

Comment: for the rails project, where to put this file? and where to run the above npm install commands?

Answer (score 9):

First make sure to install react, babble and other dependencies in your solution using

```
   npm install react --save
```

then in the web pack config file please include `presets` in the `query` similar to below:

```
   module.exports = {
entry: 'main.jsx',
output: {
    // Output the bundled file.
    path: './src',
    // Use the name specified in the entry key as name for the bundle file.
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['react']
        }
    }]
},
externals: {
    // Don't bundle the 'react' npm package with the component.
    'react': 'React'
},
resolve: {
    // Include empty string '' to resolve files by their explicit extension
    // (e.g. require('./somefile.ext')).
    // Include '.js', '.jsx' to resolve files by these implicit extensions
    // (e.g. require('underscore')).
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are watching same course 'React.js on Rails: Building a Full Stack Web App' by Samer Buna

To solve the problem i installed this modules:

`npm install react --save`

`npm install babel-preset-es2015`

`npm install babel-preset-react`

And i am using this configuration
https://jsfiddle.net/daronwolff/11tgotvz/

Thanks to @milad-rezazadeh and @chrissavage