# React: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi I am getting the following error and what every I tried I could find what in my setting is wrong (Using react sample from https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) my Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: c:\temp\react-slingshot\src\index.js Unexpected token (13:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (13:2)
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1483:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:330:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:225:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:204:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:151:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:133:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:110:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprList (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:657:23)
    at Parser.pp.parseSubscripts (C:\temp\react-slingshot\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:249:29)
 @ multi main
```

My WebPack config:

```
resolved by Chrome when they're parsed from a dynamically loaded CSS blob. Note: Only necessary in Dev.
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS), // Tells React to build in prod mode. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.htmlnew webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel'],query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

My package.json

```
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.*",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.*",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.*",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.8.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.12.5",
   ...
    "webpack": "^1.12.*",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.10.0"
  },
```

My Code index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
require('./favicon.ico'); // Tell webpack to load favicon.ico
import './styles/styles.scss'; // Yep, that's right. You can import SASS/CSS files too! Webpack will run the associated loader and plug this into the page.

const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: P.S I checked similar questions, I didn't fined any syntax mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack module build failed unexpected token (rails react build)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024628/webpack-module-build-failed-unexpected-token-rails-react-build)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget to add 'react' into the babel preset?

```
presets: ['es2015']
```

to

```
presets: ['react', 'es2015']
```

don't forget to install it

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

Comment: I am not sure what it exactly does I have added to the webpack presets as instructed but still getting the same error, this  drives me crazy

Comment: wait what do you mean with "install it" npm install/update I did, no change

Comment: Sorry, same result, what I dont understand that it worked but then after some react native installation it stopped. so I reseed the project removed all global libraries and still I get this error. frustrating

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with the call to `Provider` (line 13:2), which is the first time you're referencing one of your imported modules.

Try:

-- add this line to your webpack config in the JS loader (at the same level as `include`)

`exclude: /node_modules/`

-- remove the node modules by force and re-install just to make sure they weren't corrupted:

`$ rm -rf node_modules`

`$ npm install`

Comment: Also you need to add the 'react' preset, as Michael mentioned below, but I assume you've already done that at this point.